# MS Access: How to load data from query into form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that helps the user add some data into a Database, however I noticed that a few of the fields on each product added are very similar. So I'm adding a second database of commonly used fields that can be pre-filled by selecting from a combo-box.
For example if the user is adding Product XX-X but product XX-X is of the same family of YY-Y and I already have YY-Y's data in Database2, I want to just load those parameters. I made a query that returns the parameters as I want however I dont know how to add this to the FORM.
Basically I have a blank VBA code slot for "ComboBox_Change".
I want the ComboBox_Change function to load field X from query and paste it into field X1 on the current form.
Hope I'm explaining myself correctly.
Thanks!

*THANKS for the suggestion* this is the code so far that has an error

```
Private Sub LoadMatCB_Change()
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim db As Database

Set db = CurrentDb

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("VendorDeetsQuery")

If Nz(Me.Input_Vendor.Value, "") = "" Then Me.Input_Vendor.Value = rs![Origin]

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble following exactly what you want. What objects do you currently have on your form. I understand there is a comboBox - when the user changes the comboBox - are you trying to take the selected value, and set the rowsource of another form object?

Comment: No, The form has multiple fields (IE, part number, description, manufacturer, country of origin etc). Part numbers are unique but say we buy 10 articles from the same manufacturer, they all come from the same country and a lot of the properties are the same. To avoid retyping everything I want the user to just select manufacturer from a combo box and have all the fields initially blank in the form pre-filled

Comment: can you guarantee that you will only have one option from your query for each blank field? Or would you just use whatever is in the first record?

Comment: Yes, the search query is on a table ID, unique values only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the table's ID field to grab the related record from your query into a recordset object. You can then use the fields of the recordset to set the value in each of the other fields you want to populate; you can add the if statements to check if the controls are blank if that is a condition you need.

```
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim db as Database
    Dim qry as QueryDef

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qry = db.QueryDefs("YourQueryName")

    qry.Parameters("ParamName") = comboBox.Value '<pass your parameter here>
    'repeat the above for any other parameters you need to pass

    Set rs = qry.OpenRecordset

    'for each of these, use your control names and whatever you named the fields from your query'
    If Nz(Me.txtBox1.Value, "") = "" Then Me.txtBox1 = rs![fieldName1] 
    If Nz(Me.txtBox2.Value, "") = "" Then Me.txtBox2 = rs![fieldName2]
    ...
    ...
    If Nz(Me.txtBoxN.Value, "") = "" Then Me.txtBoxN = rs![fieldNameN]

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set qry = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Question, the rs definition, is that a query you are making? I had already made a query that gave me the results I wanted I dont know if that would help at all. Something like If Nz(Me.txtbox.Value, "") = "" Then Me.txtBox = myQuery.results.field1 (or something like that, I dont really know VBA much)

Comment: @dvd.Void if you have a query object built already, you can open the recordset by referencing the query object's name. like: `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("MyQueryName")` the rest would be the same.

Comment: @dvd.Void - PS - if your query has parameters, the set up is a little different. Let me know if this helps :-)

Comment: Hi, yes the query has parameters based on the comboBox. (Basically the query returns the vendor from the combo box selection). As of now with the code you suggested I get "Run-time error '3061: too few parameters. Expected 1". Edited OP with code

Comment: @dvd.Void - I've updated my answer to help with passing parameters and opening the recordset. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. Current error says "3265: Item not found in this collection". I am curious as to why, the combo box itself loads from the table so I'm not changing anything or typing anything at all. I am not sure if maybe the Parameter might be the issue? (I already have some set parameters in the query design itself ([Forms]![NewItem]![LoadMatCB])

Comment: qry.Parameters("Vendor") = LoadMatCB.Value. If I highlight the LoadMatCb.Value I can see the correct value that I selected but they first half qry.Parameters("Vendor") = <Item not found in this collection>. Thats why I mentioned that my query design already has some calloout to the form's combobox. I don tknow if this might make some redundancy error. EDIT: Also tried deleting that criteria on the query design. still get the same error

Comment: @dvd.Void This usually happens when there are not Parameters set up for the query. If you take a look at your query object's SQL, it should start with something like `PARAMETERS Vendor Text ( 255 );` If not, it would seem that no parameters are declared. Try adding that line, or Add the parameter using the Parameters ribbon control in the query's Design View editor.

Comment: You are correct, it didnt have that line. However with that line I dont get the error anymore but regardless of what I select on the drop down list I awlays get the values of the first entry on the table (the query isnt filtering anymore). If I add the "Criteria" on the design view (not the SQL) then I get the error again but now it asks for 2 parameters instead of 1. (Before it said Expected 1, now it says Expected 2_

Comment: With a Parameter now declared in your query object, you should be using it somewhere in the `WHERE` clause, right? So somewhere in the SQL you should have `...WHERE table.vender = Vender...` My guess is that you have this hardcoded to something instead of using the Parameter....?

Comment: THank you. Got it fixed. I was using the GUI to set up the Criteria and filters of the query. Had to set them manually via the SQL "code" or whatever. using WHERE statement.  Thanks!