# How to Prefill form from another DB based on the field value

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a solution to fetch data for a new record of SmallDB from secondary BigDB.

I created a linked table of BigDB to have it on SmallDB, so later I could use OnClick event of Button and it would be easier to reach that data.

Situation: I search form for the PersonID, but get negative result (this particular PersonID doesn't exist).

Then, in the form I create new record and enter this new Person ID in the PersonID field.

My plan is to be able to click FetchData button and pre-fill Name, Last Name and other details to the form from BigDB for this particular PersonID.

Then I would save the record with save button.

It looks to me, that solution could be similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180365

But I don't know how to ensure that I would get data from BigDB only for that particular PersonID that I entered into Form field.

Or perhaps in my situation another method would work better?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you searching for PersonID? Are you using a combobox? Combobox NotInList event is useful to run code to add new record when item is not in list.

Comment: Hi, @June7, Thank you for the code suggestion! the PersonID is located in the regular Text field. Currently I'm trying to solve couple of problems ("Type mismatch" and "Too few parameters expected 1" ). I already have several possible causes and moving from table to query and changing other things to have the form element in the SQL code. Code is working if I'm running it from the Access SQL window, but not from the form. Slowly I'm moving forward.

Answer (score 0):

Following example code from link referenced in question, apply filter criteria to query object via PARAMETERS. However, unless you have query object set up with PARAMETERS clause, I don't see need for QueryDefs and instead of referencing query object, can use SQL statement in code.

Assuming PersonID is a text type field:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE PersonID='" & Me.tbxPID & "'")
If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
```

If you are not on new record row of form, either first move to it manually or with code, or use another approach. An INSERT SELECT action SQL can create a new record in SmallDB with data from BigDB.